# Use a variable name to change the name of another variable name

Tags: php

I post two values through a form:

```
$lang       = "fr"
$about_xx   = "hello, world!
```

I now need to change the name of `$about_xx` to `$about_en`, using the `$lang` variable's value. Is this possible?

**EDIT: Added code for extra clarity and assistance. The variable `$lang` in this instance has a value `"fr"`. The compare section needs amending to support these new variables I wish to create, as opposed to ones ending `_en`**

```
// Get POST Variables
$expo_id                       = $_POST['expo_id'];
$lang                          = $_POST['lang'];
${"new_expo_url_" . $lang}     = $_POST['expo_url_lang'];
${"new_expo_venue_" . $lang}   = $_POST['expo_venue_lang'];
${"new_expo_country_" . $lang} = $_POST['expo_country_lang'];
${"new_expo_about_" . $lang}   = $_POST['expo_about_lang'];
// Get Current Variables
$update_expo = mysql_query("SELECT expo_id, expo_url_{$lang}, expo_venue_{$lang}, expo_country_{$lang}, expo_about_{$lang} FROM exhibitions WHERE expo_id = $expo_id LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($update_expo) == 0) {
    header("Location: index.php?expo_id=" . $expo_id . "&i=no-expo");
    exit();
}
// Compare
$update_lang_append = "";
while ($ula = mysql_fetch_assoc($update_expo)) {
    if ($ula['expo_venue_en'] !== $new_expo_venue_en) {
        $update_lang_append .= "expo_venue_en = '" . $new_expo_venue_en . "', ";
    }
    if ($ula['expo_country_en'] !== $new_expo_country_en) {
        $update_lang_append .= "expo_country_en = '" . $new_expo_country_en . "', ";
    }
    if ($ula['expo_about_en'] !== $new_expo_about_en) {
        $update_lang_append .= "expo_about_en = '" . $new_expo_about_en . "', ";
    }
    if (($ula['expo_url_en'] !== $new_expo_url_en) && ($new_expo_url_en !== "")) {
        $update_lang_append .= "expo_url_en = '" . $new_expo_url_en . "', ";
    }
    if ($update_lang_append == "") {
        header("Location: exhibition-edit.php?expo_id=" . $expo_id . "&i=no-change");
        exit();
    }
    else {
        $update_query_append = substr($update_query_append, 0, -2);
        $update_query = mysql_query("UPDATE exhibitions SET " . $update_query_append . " WHERE expo_id = $expo_id") or die(mysql_error());
        header("Location: index.php?i=success");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot *change* a variable name, however you can use *variable variables* as [explained in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). However, this seems like a very bad design. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: Don't use [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) - they are usually unneeded and make code more convoluted in the end. Use a proper data-structure (like an "array" with keys).

Comment: My form is what's used to add "about text" to a database record, and caters to multiple languages. The database is set up with column names `about_en`, `about_de`, `about_fr`, etc. I need to use one form, with an input named `about_xx` and a hidden field containing the variable `lang` and one "add to database" script.

Comment: I still have no idea why it needs to be a *variable variable name*. Use arrays!

Comment: Added code for clarity.

Comment: Again: use arrays! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

```
${"about_".$lang} = "hello, world!"
```

Although, [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are generally considered bad practise (I mean, *look* at it). You should instead use an array for this. I.E:

```
$about = Array();
$about[$lang] = "hello, world";
```

---

**After OP Edit**

Create your array like so:

```
$new_expo = Array();
$new_expo['url'][$lang]        = $_POST['expo_url_lang'];
$new_expo['venue'][$lang]      = $_POST['expo_venue_lang'];
```

Call your keys in a similar way, I.E:

```
$update_lang_append .= "expo_venue_en = '" . $new_expo['venue']['en'] . "', ";
```

Comment: So if I've posted multiple values: `about_xx`, `venue_xx`, `country_xx`, `location_xx`, how can I use that array to create multiple named variables?

Comment: @MatthewPeckham Check the edit. You should be able to continue from here by yourself.

Comment: */facepalm* Just realised if I sent my values with an `<input name="expo_about_<?=$lang?>"` then it saves all my hard work on this page! :)